# How to convert byte array to binary values and then write it in a comma separated text file

Tags: c#

I have a byte array:

```
newMsg.DATA = new byte[64];
```

How can I convert it into binary value and then write it in text file with comma separation. Comma should be in between binary values not bytes.....

like 1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0.......

Comment: There are several steps here: 1) Extracting individual bits from a byte; 2) Converting bits to strings; 3) Creating a comma-separated representation; 4) Writing that text to a file. Please show what you've tried so far - at the moment there's no sign that you've tried anything, which makes it less likely that others will help you.

Comment: every subquestion in this post has been asked here multiple times. Please put some effort in research first., Then please post the code that you have and explain where you got stuck. Good luck

Comment: So what _should_ be between the bytes then? Because your example _does_ have commas between the values beyond 8 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will Help you c# provides inbuilt functionality to do so

with help of Convert.ToString(byte[],base); here base could be[2(binary),8(octal),16(HexaDecimal)]

```
        byte[] data = new byte[64];
        // 2nd parameter 2 is Base e.g.(binary)
        string a = Convert.ToString(data[data.Length], 2);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char ch in a.ToCharArray())
        {
            sb.Append(ch+",");
        }
        // This is to remove last extra ,
        string ans = sb.ToString().Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
```

Comment: it might be confusing if you don't explain why you chose to convert only the byte at position `20`. Also a little bit more explanation would really improve your answer. like: `ToString(data[20], 2);` what is the meaning of the `2` ?=! :)

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks for suggestions. did edit answer according to that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that uses LINQ:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] { 11, 55, 255, 188, 99, 22, 31, 43, 25, 122 };

string[] result = arr.Select(x => string.Join(",", Convert.ToString(x, 2)
                     .PadLeft(8, '0').ToCharArray())).ToArray();

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\myFile.txt", result);
```

Every number in `byte[] arr` is converted to a binary number with `Convert.ToString(x, 2)` and the comma `","` is added between  binary values with `string.Join(",",...)`. At the end you can write all the elements in `result` to a text file by using `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`.

The example above gives you this kind of output in a txt file:

```
0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1
0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
...
```

**Explanation of** `Convert.ToString(value, baseValue)`:

The first parameter `value` represents the number you want to convert to a string 
and the second parameter `baseValue` represents which type of conversion you want to perform.

Posible `baseValues` are : `2,8,10 and 16.`

`BaseValue = 2` - represents a conversion to a binary number representation.

`BaseValue = 8` - represents a conversion to a octal number representation.

`BaseValue = 10` - represents a conversion to a decimal number representation.

`BaseValue = 16` - represents a conversion to a hexadecimal number representation.

Comment: the only answer with a decent explanation. Have an upvote. May be you could explain the meaning of the `2` in `Convert.ToString(x, 2)`

Comment: @MongZhu are you pleased with the explanation

Comment: amazed ;) more than thorough! I would upvote once more if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 128, 255, 2 };
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (var index = 0; index < bytes.Length; index++)
{
    var binary = Convert.ToString(bytes[index], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    var str = string.Join(",", binary.ToCharArray());
    stringBuilder.Append(str);
    if (index != bytes.Length -1) stringBuilder.Append(",");
}
Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
```

Comment: This line var str = string.Join(",", binary.ToCharArray()); is  giving error......its saying best overload method is string.join(string,string[])